# Creating relationship between two previously disconnected nodes

Tags: neo4j

Given query:

```
start n=node(*)
match p:Person, b:Book
where p.name = 'John' AND b.title = 'KJV'
create p-[r:OWNS]->b
return r
```

error: `Expected return clause` is thrown, with a caret pointing at the `S]`

What is the syntactical error?

Comment: post the error and neo4j version you are using.

Comment: @Pangea: 1.9.2 - the error is contained within a gigantic neoeclipse box and not copyabile.

Comment: Check my edit to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are using older version of Neo4j (< 2.0) which doesn't support Labels. I was able to successfully create the relationships using the below Cypher. Tried it on console.neo4j.org

```
CREATE (n:Person { name : 'John' })
CREATE (n:Book { title : 'KJV' })
start n=node(*)
match p:Person, b:Book
where p.name = 'John' AND b.title = 'KJV'
create p-[r:OWNS]->b
return r
```

**EDIT**

As I've guessed, you are using 1.9.2 which doesn't support Labels. You however are using the Neo4j 2.0 syntax with Labels (`p:Person`, `b:Book`)

Comment: Answer selected: "you're using the wrong version, noob." :-) thanks.